# <option> is having each option its own dropdown

Tags: php, html

I tried putting the loop inside but then when I pick a category it won't print in the echo and if the loop is outside like right now each category is printed alone I want them all in one tab and one go button

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $row["category"];
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="work_place">
            <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?></option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </form>
<?php
}
<?php
    $post = (isset($_POST['work_place'])) ? $_POST['work_place'] : '';
    echo $post;
?>
```

Image of current issue:

[image: image of current issue]

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="work_place">
  <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $row["category"];
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?>
      </option>
<?php
  } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

You want to loop over 'option', only.
You do not want multiple forms and 'select' inputs.

Comment: When i do that i have one list but the echo function stops working

Comment: The value of $_POST['work_place'] may be empty. Select a non empty option before submit.

Comment: when i set the loop outside it echos correctly but when the loop is only over option it stops echoing